# Extracting values from arbitrary/named associative arrays and keys within them

Tags: bash, shell

I use `declare -A` to add key-value pairs in dictionary.

```
APP_LIST=('app1' 'app2')
declare -A app1=([column_a]="111" [column_b]="222")
declare -A app2=([column_a]="333" [column_b]="444")
```

I have tried to print the value of the column_b from app1 and app2 using for-loop, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
for i in ${APP_LIST[*]}; do
    echo ${${i}[column_b]}
done
```

The error msg:

```
 ${${i}[column_b]}: bad substitution
```

Please help, thanks!

I expected to print the value of the `column_b` from app1 and app2 using for-loop.

Comment: I've edited the title to incorporate the part of the question that makes this interesting (needing to indirectly address the associative arrays themselves and not just the keys within them). And because the question depends on bash-only features, updated to tag this [tag:bash] rather than just [tag:shell].

Comment: (Also, the thing you're trying to do is an "indirect reference", and bash calls its maps "associative arrays"; use those two terms, and search comes up with an on-point duplicate -- mind, please _don't_ delete your question just because it's closed; duplicate flags that give us more synonyms to search for questions that are posed in terms different from those in the prior/canonical example are exactly the kind of duplicate question we need and want in our knowledge base; that's reflected in how questions that are closed as duplicate can still be upvoted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

app_list=('app1' 'app2')
declare -A app1=([column_a]="111" [column_b]="222")
declare -A app2=([column_a]="333" [column_b]="444")

declare -n arr_name
for arr_name in "${app_list[@]}"; do
    echo "${arr_name[column_b]}"
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
222
444
```